# Authorization header not persisting after webpage refresh in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js application where different components, as shown below, fetches data using axios. However, when I refresh the browser page, the authorization header appears to be missing, hence unsuccessful data fetching with an api response of `{"message":"authorization header is empty"}` . I'm using getServerSideProps to pass the user object to the each component initially. Below is a layout of different components.

```
const ComponentsPageLayout = () => { 
return (
<>
  <NavBar />
  <DashboardLayout>
    <h4>Insights</h4>
    <InfoCard />
    <Container className="mt-9 ml-[-10px]">
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
    </Container>
  </DashboardLayout>
</>
);
 };
 export const getServerSideProps = RequireAuthentication(
 async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
return {
  props: {session: await getSession(ctx)},

};

 },
  );
```

Below is Component1.

```
import  {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {axios} from '@/utils/axios';

 // Define types
 interface OverviewStats {
 revenue_earned: number;
 marketing_cost: number;
 customers_engaged: number;
 }


 export default function InsightsCardInfo() {
 const [period, setPeriod] = useState<string>('30 days');
 const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState<Date[]>([]);
 const [overviewStats, setOverviewStats] = useState<OverviewStats | null>(
 null,
);

   const EndpointURL = ``;

    useEffect(() => {
     const fetchInitialData = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const endDate: Date = new Date();
      const startDate: Date = new Date();
     startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 30);
       setSelectedDates([startDate, endDate]);
       const formattedStartDate: string = format(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
     const formattedEndDate: string = format(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      const response = await axios.get(
      `${EndpointURL}/overview? 
  start_date=${formattedStartDate}&end_date=${formattedEndDate}`,
  );

  setOverviewStats(response?.data);
};
fetchInitialData();
}, []);



 return (
 <>
  </>
 );
}
```

here is the axios configuration :

```
import HttpClient from 'axios';
import {signOut} from 'next-auth/react';
import {CurrentLoggedInUser} from './types/shared';
import {getSelectedMerchantId} from './helpers/merchantHelpers';

const baseURL = process.env.API_BASE_URL as string;

const axios = HttpClient.create({
baseURL,
withCredentials: false, // Add this line to set withCredentials to false
});

 function axiosClient(user: CurrentLoggedInUser | null) {
 if (user) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${user.auth_token}`;
 const selectedMerchantId = getSelectedMerchantId();
  axios.defaults.headers.common.merchantID = `${selectedMerchantId}`;
 }

 axios.interceptors.response.use(
   (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
  const statusCode = error && error.response ? error.response.status : 0;
    if (statusCode === 401 && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    signOut();
    window.location.href = '/portal/auth/login';
   }
   return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

  return axios;
  }

 export {axios, axiosClient};
```